# Imprimir dados de um JSON

Tags: php, json

Eu tenho uma consulta SQL que eu já testei e ela está trazendo o resultado correto, a minha dificuldade é em criar um array com os dados da linha,  transformá-lo em JSON e imprimir na tela.

Quando eu tento com um array de strings, dá certo, quando eu tento com um array de variáveis contendo strings, dá errado...

```
require '../conn/conn.php';

$conn = new Conn();
$conecta = $conn->conecta();

//essa consulta está retornando resultados, eu já testei
$sql = "SELECT u.id_user, u.nome, u.cargo, u.setor, u.usuario,  p.nome 
FROM usuarios as u 
INNER JOIN permissoes as p ON (u.permissao = p.id_permissao)";

$result = mysqli_query($conecta, $sql);

$encode = null;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //dessa forma não está dando certo
    $encode[] = array( $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);

 //quando eu tento da forma abaixo dá certo e imprime o json numa boa
 // $encode[] = array("palavra1", "palavra2", "palavra3");
}

$conecta->close();
echo json_encode($encode);

}else{

echo "consulta vazia";
}
```

**Exemplo de array com strings (funciona)**

```
$encode[] = array("palavra1", "palavra2", "palavra3");
```

**Exemplo de array com variáveis (não funciona)**

```
$encode[] = array($row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);
```

Comment: $encode[] = $row;

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta um exemplo do `array de strings` e `array de variáveis`

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior são esses aqui: array com variáveis `$encode[] = array( $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);` e agora com strings `$encode[] = array("palavra1", "palavra2", "palavra3");` .
O segundo funciona o primeiro não.

Comment: @VictorAraujo esse tipo de informação deve ficar na pergunta pois pode ajudar outros usuários, pode deixar que já vou editar aqui.

Comment: Qual é o valor de `$row[1]`?

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior o primeiro $row[1] é "Administrador", o segundo é "Teste Saúde", que está de acordo com o banco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olha como deve ser o seu `while`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
    $encode[] = $row;
}
```

depois do laço faço o `echo` assim:

```
echo json_encode( Array('json'=>$encode) );
```

Isso se precisar da formatação tipo `json` no padrão, se não nem precisa mudar nada aqui

**EDIT:**

Conforme seu resultado em comentário abaixo o código esta funcionando, talvez não esteja conseguindo somente usa-lo, vou te ajudar nessa parte agora:

Vamos entender o que o `var_dump()` nos trouxe:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "1" 
        [1]=> string(13) "Administrador" 
        [2]=> string(13) "Administrador" 
        [3]=> string(2) "RH" 
        [4]=> string(5) "admin" 
        [5]=> string(5) "Total" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(6) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "2" 
        [1]=> string(11) "Teste Sa?de" 
        [2]=> string(7) "Gerente" 
        [3]=> string(9) "Marketing" 
        [4]=> string(11) "teste-saude" 
        [5]=> string(5) "Sa?de" 
    } 
}
```

Temos um array, e na posição 1 temos o primeiro registro com `u.id_user, u.nome, u.cargo, u.setor, u.usuario,  p.nome` para usa-lo para usa-lo em php seria assim:

```
echo $enconde[0][0] // pega o u.id_user
echo $enconde[0][1] // pega o u.nome
echo $enconde[0][2] // pega o u.cargo
echo $enconde[0][3] // pega o u.setor
echo $enconde[0][4] // pega o u.usuario
echo $enconde[0][5] // pega o u.nome
```

se mudarmos o primeiro indice para 1 terá os resultados do **segundo** registro do seu select, agora como mexer com isso em javascript? segue abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(json) {
  alert( json[0][0] ); // // pega o u.id_user
});
```

**BONUS:**

Particularmente eu gosto de trabalhar com o conceito de objetos uma simples olhada na funcao **mysql_fetch_object()** lhe traria resultados assim:

**PHP**

```
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){    
    $encode[] = $obj; // enchendo um array com objetos
}

$obj = $encode[0] // pegando o primeiro objeto
echo $obj->user_id // mostra o id
echo $obj->nome // mostra o nome, opa nome do USUARIO ou da PERMISSAO ? eu já iria colocar uma alias no select para desambiguar isso
...
...
```

**javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(json) {
  var obj = json[0];
  alert( obj.id_user ); // pega o id_user
});
```

Comment: Também, não está dando certo =/

Comment: da um `var_dump($encode)` e debuga, tem msg de erro, warnig, notice alguma coisa ?

Comment: o resultado do var_dump é _array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "Administrador" [2]=> string(13) "Administrador" [3]=> string(2) "RH" [4]=> string(5) "admin" [5]=> string(5) "Total" } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(11) "Teste Sa�de" [2]=> string(7) "Gerente" [3]=> string(9) "Marketing" [4]=> string(11) "teste-saude" [5]=> string(5) "Sa�de" } }_ e não da erro nenhum no log do php.

Comment: obs: eu mudei o código para `mysqli_fetch_row`

Comment: @VictorAraujo fiz uma edição, com isso acho que você resolver o problema todo

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, consegui aqui agora, usei a dica do Objeto e do Alias, eu não sabia como fazer isso antes, valeu mesmo!!!